# Why git don't ignore all some directory?

Tags: git

This is my git directory on my PC:

```
├───.idea
│   ├───inspectionProfiles
│   └───runConfigurations
├───dist
├───src
│   ├───beans
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───files
│   ├───unifiAdopter.egg-info
│   └───__pycache__
├───tests
├───unifiAdopter.egg-info
└───venv
    ├───Include
    ├───Lib
    └───Scripts
```

I want to ignore directory `.idea`, `dist` and `venv`.
I wrote this '.gitignore` file:

```
venv/
dist/
.idea/
```

And i did this command:

```
git rm --cached venv/ -r
git rm --cached dist/ -r
git rm --cached .idea/ -r
```

It's work for the entire `.idea`and `dist` but not the whole `venv` file is being ignored. This is my repository tree:

```
src/unifiadopter/
├── _config.yml
├── LICENSE.txt
├── MANIFEST.in
├── README.md
├── setup.py
├── src
│   ├── beans
│   ├── controllers
│   ├── Counter.py
│   ├── Ctrl.py
│   ├── DateTools.py
│   ├── files
│   ├── helpers
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── Restorer.py
│   ├── Ssh.py
│   ├── unifiAdopter.egg-info
│   ├── unifiAdopter.py
│   ├── workers
│   └── XmlReader.py
├── tests
│   ├── compter.py
│   ├── readerTest.py
│   ├── test4.py
│   ├── testModuleDeploy.py
│   ├── testSsh2.py
│   ├── testSsh3.py
│   └── testSsh.py
├── unifiAdopter.egg-info
│   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   ├── PKG-INFO
│   ├── requires.txt
│   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   └── top_level.txt
└── venv
    └── Lib
```

Comment: Can you try ./venv in .gitignore and see whether it works ?

Comment: Looks right to me, so the problem is possibly caused by something not mentioned in this question.

Comment: There is no change but `/venv/Lib/` are written in grey. If you would see: [my github](https://github.com/simbarras/unifiAdopter) @awadheshpathak

Comment: And what is the solution@Thomas?

Comment: When I do `git status` all files in `venv/Lib/site-packages` are marked as deleted fromindex and `venv/`is marked as ignored.

Comment: Shouldn't be `venv/*`?

Comment: Can you try with exact same gitignore and a fresh repo? IOW are old contents of venv messing the gitignore? Also the "-r" in the rm should be previous to the path "venv" I think. And after that commit as said by "Bach"

Comment: Come to think of it why have the trailing "/"? (Or leading)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an existing commit in which some `venv/Lib/` files exist.

You specifically told Git to *remove* those files from Git's index, using `git rm --cached venv/ -r`, and it did so.  You also told Git to treat those files as "to be ignored" when they are untracked, so it is doing so.

Let's call your current commit `C`, for "current", and your next commit—which you have not yet made, but which will get a commit number (a hash ID) when you make it, commit `D`.  (You will have to run `git commit` to make it, and the hash ID it gets at that time will depend on the exact second at which you run `git commit`.)

`git status` now shows those files as deleted because when comparing commit `C` to the proposed (but not yet existing) commit `D`, one of the differences *between* `C` and the projected `D` is that the `venv/Lib/` files will no longer exist.  In other words, between `C` and `D`, those files will be deleted.  Git is showing this to you.

The ignored-ness of any untracked files that may or may not exist in `venv/` is entirely irrelevant.  Commit `C` *has* `venv/Lib/` files, and commit `D` won't.  So those files will be shown as deleted whenever `C` is compared to `D`.

(To put it another way: `.gitignore` does not mean that Git should *ignore* those files.  It means *don't complain about files that are untracked, and don't make them tracked.*)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should give "git commit" a try.